# Don't break lines at certain characters in lstlisting

Tags: listings

Is it possible to configure lstlisting such that it doesn't break lines at certain characters? In this example, a line break is inserted after the opening parenthesis:

```
public void someMethod(
    String parameter)
```

Instead, I would like the opening parenthesis to appear in the second line:

```
public void someMethod
    (String parameter)
```

**Edit** (MWE added):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true, linewidth=5cm, frame=single]
public void someMethod(String parameter)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's relevant (I would need to see a MWE), but the `listings` package can perform some automatic code formatting; however, that feature is relatively limited and only documented in the developer's guide, at the moment.

Comment: Ok, I've added an MWE. The output looks like the first example in the question.

Comment: In this case the best solution is probably to add a space between the `d` and the `(`.

Comment: If you only have short, embedded listings (i.e. listings inside `lstlisting` environments as opposed to listings inserted with `\lstinputlisting`), it's easier to simply follow karlkoeller's advice: introduce some spaces in order to allow for a line break where desired.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I think, that might work, although I would prefer a solution that doesn't require changes in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What follows is more an ugly hack than a proper solution, but it might just do the trick for you.

In a nutshell, the approach consists locally setting a very high line-breaking penalty right after any occurence of the `(` character in listings; that way, no line break can occur after `(`, as desired.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  breaklines=true,
  frame=single,
  literate=({{(\penalty10000\hspace{-.7em}}}2, % <--- ugly hack right there
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[linewidth=5cm]
public void someMethod(String parameter)
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
public void someMethod(String parameter)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```