# Stop breaks around hyphen in lstinline

Tags: listings, hyphenation

I'm trying to stop line breaks at hyphens, *e.g.* for `\lstinline{sudo yum install -y epel-release && sudo yum install -y scipy python-matplotlib git autoconf automake screen gcc-c++ rubber texlive-appendix}`, I don't want `epel-release` nor `python-matlib` to be hyphenated.

I have the following attempt (thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200498 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119371):

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\lst@ifdisplaystyle\scriptsize\fi,
  columns=flexible,
  breaklines=true,  
  literate=-{\nobreak-\nobreak}3, % <--- 10K penalty to break around - (e.g. python-matplotlib)
}
```

This seems to work as expected, until a command comes along that has a double-hyphenated option, *e.g.* `yum --disablerepo=*`. That inserts a bunch of spaces randomly around the hyphens and looks horrible. I've added `\raggedright` to the `basicstyle` because I thought they *might* be justification, but that didn't help. Wrapping the whole paragraph with `flushleft` didn't either.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ % Set default for listings
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\lst@ifdisplaystyle\scriptsize\fi,
  columns=flexible,
  breaklines=true,  
  literate=-{\nobreak-\nobreak}3, % <--- 10K penalty to break around - (e.g. python-matplotlib) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200498 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119371
}

\begin{document}
Additional software installation: \lstinline`sudo yum install -y epel-release && sudo yum install -y scipy python-matplotlib git autoconf automake screen gcc-c++ rubber texlive-appendix`\\

Then build:\\
\lstinline`control build --build-opt1 --build-opt1-option optionA --build-opt1-option optionB --build-opt2 --build-opt2-option optionX --build-opt2-option optionY`
\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a complete example. Without it is is impossible to test solutions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Done.

Comment: Why don't you use `breakatwhitespace=true`? You don't want break inside the options anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because I'm a copypasta newb when it comes to LaTeX and didn't know about that option. ;) That definitely helps (along with removing the `literate`). If you post that as an answer and help me figure out how to get it to stop leaving overhanging text by moving the linebreak to the beginning of the too-long word, I'll accept it.